# Same type names different namespaces with Ravendb

Tags: ravendb

I'm using RavenDb. I'm storing different objects, but these objects have the same name.

```
Namespace.Models.X

abstract class A

class B : A
class C : A


Namespace.Models.Y

abstract class D

class B : D
class C : D
```

Raven is storing both types in the format:

```
Namespace.Models.X.B as type/1 
Namespace.Models.Y.B as type/2
```

Is there a way to override the collection name associated with the document?
I could change my class names but I'd rather not if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using:

```
documentStore.Conventions.FindTypeTagName = type => /* get type name as you wish it */;
```